# SQL Server convert data to JSON with batches

Tags: json, sql-server

I wish to convert data to JSON with separate batches. In each batch there should be no more than two users, without null values.

```
create table #test(userid int, status_a int, status_b int)

insert into #test values  (135, 11,23),
                          (197, 14, null),
                          (254, null,21),
                          (261, 13, 25),
                          (391, null, 17)
```

result should be

```
[
   {
      "TrackingData":[
         {
            "userid":135,
            "status_a":11,
            "status_b":23
         },
         {
            "userid":197,
            "status_a":14
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "TrackingData":[
         {
            "userid":254,
            "status_b":21
         },
         {
            "userid":261,
            "status_a":13,
            "status_b":25
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "TrackingData":[
         {
            "userid":391,
            "status_b":17
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried to do this, but don't know how to divide into to batches

```
SELECT *
FROM #test
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: I don't think what batch means, and what you mean by batch are one and the same. Can you explain what you mean by batching please? Batching, in SQL, means to do a single large task in smaller sets (a batch). For example, if you need to `UPDATE` 10,000,000 rows, you might choose to do them in batches of 1,000,000, as sometimes it can be quicker to do the same task several times, with a smaller sub set, that do them all on one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are ordering by `userid` and you want the first two in a `TrackingData` object, next pair in a `TrackingData` object and so on.

This [returns your desired results](https://dbfiddle.uk/PPc3Grlj)

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 2;

WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid) - 1,
       Json = (SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER )
FROM #test t
)
SELECT TrackingData = JSON_QUERY('[' + 
                                  STRING_AGG(Json, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RN) + 
                                  ']')
FROM T
GROUP BY RN/@BatchSize
ORDER BY RN/@BatchSize
FOR JSON PATH
```

It generates a zero based sequential row numbering and uses integer division  on that to divide into `<@BatchSize>` sized groups.

| userid | status_a | status_b | RN | RN/@BatchSize | Json |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 135 | 11 | 23 | 0 | 0 | {"userid":135,"status_a":11,"status_b":23} |
| 197 | 14 | NULL | 1 | 0 | {"userid":197,"status_a":14} |
| 254 | NULL | 21 | 2 | 1 | {"userid":254,"status_b":21} |
| 261 | 13 | 25 | 3 | 1 | {"userid":261,"status_a":13,"status_b":25} |
| 391 | NULL | 17 | 4 | 2 | {"userid":391,"status_b":17} |

The construction of the sub array is just done with string aggregation and wrapped in `JSON_QUERY` so it is treated as JSON and not escaped in the final `FOR JSON PATH`.

Comment: Thank you! If I change the number of objects from 2 to 5 or 1000 it won`t work, yes?

Comment: @AnastasiiaVerbytska - this is customisable now